# Largest possible families of a set of n elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

Let $\mathcal F$ be a family of subsets of *a set consisting of* $n$ *elements* so that no element of $\mathcal F$ is a subset of another element. Prove that $\mathcal F$ can have at most $$\binom{n}{\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor}.$$

Are these partitions? I suspected I could use induction, but it isn't really clear.

Award task, Socialist Republic Croatia, Yugoslavia 1973

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I don't at all see how this would be equivalent to the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ being mutually disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [Sperner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem).